# Q: Babylonian tablet for pi=3.125

Tags: math-history, pi

I read an article about Babylonian pi. https://numberwarrior.wordpress.com/2008/12/03/on-the-ancient-babylonian-value-for-pi/

The author wrote that Babylonians used 25/8 as pi. But, he could not show the tablet for copyright reasons. He gave some link for the tablet. But, they were not available now.

Is there someone who knows the picture of the tablet?

Comment: If the link is available maybe [the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org) did crawl it.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate for [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Oh, I see. I found the page https://cdli.ucla.edu/search/search_results.php?SearchMode=Text&ObjectID=P254835 using the wayback machine. Thank you. But, "No Image Available" in the page. :-(

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I didn't know History of Science and Mathematics. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The tablet is YBC $7302$; it’s in the Peabody Museum of Natural History and can be seen [here](https://collections.peabody.yale.edu/search/Record/YPM-BC-021367). It (and much else) is discussed in Christine Proust, [*Floating calculation in Mesopotamia*](https://cdli.ucla.edu/pubs/cdlp/cdlp0005_20160501.pdf) [PDF], Cuneiform Digital Library Preprints; see pp. $15$ and $16$. It appears that the calculation actually uses the approximation $\pi\approx 3$. This appears to be the generally accepted interpretation of the tablet.

Comment: YBC 7302 shows that Babylonians used 3 as pi s you said. But the tablet P254835 or TMS 03 shows that they also used  ≈ 3 1/8. But I couldn't find the picture of the tablet.